# Apache httpd does not load index.html when a web app is installed

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, scientific-linux

In a CentOS 7 installation I installed OrangeScrum (which is a standard PHP application copied to `/var/www/html`). When I type the server IP I get the Apache test page and if I have an `index.html` page it will be displayed. And when I type the `server-ip/orangescrum` for example I get the web app. All this is fine.

Moving on to a server with Scientific Linux 7 I did the same, but when I install the app to the Apache and typing the server ip alone I get the app itself not the Apache status nor the `index.html` if any. Nothing has been done to `httpd.conf` except adding a virtual host definition like [here](https://www.orangescrum.org/how-to-install-orangescrum-on-centos)

What am I missing to do in order to get the root index or the Apache test pages to work?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, however, what is in `/var/www/html` on your Scientific Linux 7 system ? Do you have an `.htaccess` file with redirect there ?

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the existing `index.html` file from `/var/www/html` directory or rename it to something line `index.html.back`. Then you shall start seeing your application while typing IP address.

Your server indexing `.html` file before `.php` file. Sub folders of the application doesn't have any `.html` file. So, it's working fine.

If this solve your issue update your virtual host configuration as follows

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scientific Linux 7, you copied the contents of `orangescrum` to `/var/www/html` instead of copying the whole directory to make it look like this `/var/www/html/orangescrum`